# SQL XML .node .query() returns empty string instead of NULL if table node exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xml-parsing

Why does .query() return empty string instead of NULL if the table doesn't exist?  I am new to querying xml in SQL so I am just playing around and this was unexpected.

Here is an example of the problem.

```
declare @xml xml

set @xml = N'<xdoc><Header><OrderID>1234</OrderID><Detail><ProductID>12345</ProductID><Amount>12.50</Amount></Detail></Header></xdoc>'

SELECT  
    Tbl.Col.value('OrderID[1]', 'varchar(10)') as OrderID,  
    Tbl.Col.query('Detail') as Detail
FROM @xml.nodes('//Header') Tbl(Col)

set @xml = N'<xdoc><Header><OrderID>1234</OrderID></Header></xdoc>'

SELECT  
    Tbl.Col.value('OrderID[1]', 'varchar(10)') as OrderID,  
    Tbl.Col.query('Detail') as Detail
FROM @xml.nodes('//Header') Tbl(Col)
```

The first select statement returns as expected.  The Detail field is the xml of the table detail within the header.

However, on the second select statement this header record did not have a detail table so I expected the field to be null instead of empty string.

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJTxz.png)

Comment: XML support is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: `query` method generally implements [a part of] `XQuery` specification https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/  which has no notion of null. The method returns null only when applied to null sql xml value (sql server).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is possible, but you must think a little bit differently. In XML the value `NULL` is indicated by a **missing node**.

Furthermore, the word **"value"** is very important in this sentence. The `.value()` method will return `NULL` if the element you are looking for is not present. The `.query()`-method will return a XML-typed fragment in any case.

XML consits of nodes. Elements (any `<SomeElement>` together with all nested nodes) are a special kind of node. The floating text within an element is a node in itself. Look at these examples:

Your XML

```
declare @xml xml

set @xml = 
N'<xdoc>
  <Header>
    <OrderID>1234</OrderID>
    <Detail>
      <ProductID>12345</ProductID>
      <Amount>12.50</Amount>
    </Detail>
  </Header>
</xdoc>'
```

--`.query()` can return the `<Detail>`-fragment

```
SELECT @xml.query('/xdoc/Header/Detail');

<Detail>
  <ProductID>12345</ProductID>
  <Amount>12.50</Amount>
</Detail>
```

--This node does not exist. What you get back is not a **`NULL`-value** but an **empty XML node**

```
SELECT @xml.query('/xdoc/Header/Dummy');                                       --<-- empty XML
```

--Now look at `.value()`

```
SELECT @xml.value('(/xdoc/Header/Dummy)[1]','nvarchar(100)');                  --<-- NULL
SELECT @xml.value('(/xdoc/Header/Detail)[1]','nvarchar(100)');                 --<-- 1234512.50
SELECT @xml.value('(/xdoc/Header/Detail/text())[1]','nvarchar(100)');          --<-- NULL
SELECT @xml.value('(/xdoc/Header/Detail/ProductID)[1]','nvarchar(100)');       --<-- 12345
SELECT @xml.value('(/xdoc/Header/Detail/ProductID/text())[1]','nvarchar(100)');--<-- 12345
```

The first call is clear, there is no `<Dummy>`, therefore, we get a `NULL` back.
The second call might surprise you. The *value* is **everything within the element**. In this case we get a combination of all the values. You might have seen this as a trick to simulate *group_concat()*.
The third call returns `NULL` as there is no `text()` within `<Detail>`
... and the fourth and the fifth call return the same, but the last one with `text()` is most specific and therefore the best choice.

It is depending on your needs, what you want to query and what you want to get back. Furthermore, you can use predicates like `empty(SomeNode)` or `not(empty(SomeNode))` to use XQuery-filters in your XPath.